# Alert with drag and drop using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I'm still new to all this and I've been looking online but still can't figure out a way.

I have a drag and drop feature.
The user will be given an article title and is instructed to drag the article title to a box labeled 'True' or 'False'.

How can I get it to alert the user when they drop it in the 'False' box?

Tyia!!

HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="droptarget">True or False?
<div draggable="true" id="dragtarget" class="drag">Article (Drag Me!)</div>
</div>
<div class="droptarget">False</div>
<div class="droptarget">True</div>
<script src="site.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript code:

```
/* Event fired on the drag target */
document.addEventListener("dragstart", function(event) {
event.dataTransfer.setData("Text", event.target.id)
//document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Started to drag the p 
element."
})

/* Events fired on the drop target */
document.addEventListener("dragover", function(event) {
event.preventDefault()
})

document.addEventListener("drop", function(event) {
event.preventDefault()
var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("Text")
event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data))

//document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "The p element was 
dropped"
})
```

Comment: You need to be able to discern the false target and the true target. Try adding ID's and adding event listeners this way.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the target element on the `drop` event handler, via `event.target`. You also need to have a way to know it's the right element, by adding an `id`, a unique `class`, etc.

Example:

```
<div class="droptarget" id="targetFalse">False</div>
```

And on the JS:

```
document.addEventListener("drop", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    if(event.target.id==='targetFalse'){
        alert('False')
    }
...
})
```

Comment: thanks!! Could you also help me with a pop up box? So that I can tell the user if they're right or wrong and include a link to the article? Or is it possible to add a link in to the alert box?